# Google Nginx Pagespeed with Varnish increases TTFB

Tags: nginx, varnish, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Installed Pagespeed in front of Varnish proxy for fpc, #pagespeed on; and #pagespeed FileCachePath /dev/shm; (both disabled) ttfb on warmed cache is ~90ms. Uncomment FileCachePath (leaving it as the #pagespeed on; is still there) and the ttfb goes to 350ms on a warmed cache. It looks like pagespeed is adding 200-300ms to the equation, same when pagespeed is switch on, is it really that inefficient.

Comment: That is surprising, but we'd need to know more about your configuration to troubleshoot. Probably your best bet is to email us at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ngx-pagespeed-discuss . Please add more information: your entire configuration file, does every fetch get slowed down this much? etc.

Answer (score 0):

We've run many tests and never found mod_pagespeed to be this slow. That's very strange, as I mentioned in the comment, you should email the discussion forums and we can help debug.

However, on a side note, it is rather strange that you are putting mod_pagespeed after varnish, usually people put varnish after mod_pagespeed. That way all the rewritten resources can be cached efficiently by varnish.

Comment: We know, it is a different setup, we need to run some tests to remove Varnish completely and see what the difference is. We tried it also on another environment with a similar setup, same problem, 200-300ms lag when pagespeed is enabled. We will move over to the forums once we have some more information.